# Android combining queries

Tags: android, sql

I’m currently displaying a heading name and description text in two separate TextViews from one table in a database in a single activity. I’m also using two queries to return the string for both heading and description as shown in the code below.

Is there a better way of doing this, I think I can return both heading and description from a single query but I’m unsure how to display it.

Calling code:

```
beachName = dbBeachHelper.getBeachName(passedVar);
beachText = dbBeachHelper.getBeachText(passedVar);
```

Queries:

```
public String getBeachName(String id) {
    String[] args = {id};

    Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id, BeachName FROM Beach WHERE _id=?", args);
    if(c.moveToNext()){
        return(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("BeachName")));
    }
    c.close();
    return id;
}

public String getBeachText(String id) {
    String[] args = {id};

    Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id, BeachText FROM Beach WHERE _id=?", args);
    if(c.moveToNext()){
        return(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("BeachText")));
    }
    c.close();
    return id;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Mike.

**Updated**

---

I would like to return a cursor but as I said above I don’t know what to do with it when I get it back. How do I separate the cursor into two variables that I can then use to fill the TextViews???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would insist better to return the Cursor instead of String,

```
public Cursor getData(String id) {
    String[] args = {id};

    return getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id, BeachName, BeachText FROM Beach WHERE _id=?", args);

}
```

Then you can get the values from the Cursor.

**UPDATE**

```
        Cursor c = helper.getData("your id");
        c.moveToFirst();
        if(c.getCount() > 0){
            txtName.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("BeachName")));
            txtText.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("BeachText")));
        }
        c.close();
```

Comment: Thanks Lalit, very clean and worked first time! Cheers, Mike.

Answer (score 1):

This method returns array of two objects of `String` type. The first one is `BeachName`, the second one is `BeachText`:

```
public String[] getBeachNameText(String id)
{
    String[] args = { id };
    String[] result = new String[2];

    Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id, BeachName, BeachText FROM Beach WHERE _id=?", args);
    if (c.moveToNext())
    {
        result[0] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("BeachName"));
        result[1] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("BeachText"));
    }
    c.close();
    return result;
}
```